# Anotaciones de componentes Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Estoy empezando a usar [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) y, por lo que he visto, la diferencia entre las anotaciones `@Controller`, `@Repository` y `@Service` es la capa donde tienes que usarla ya que se podría decir que son una extensión/especialización de los `@Component` de Spring.

Asi, `@Repository` es para la capa de persistencia, `@Service` es para la capa de negocio y `@Controller` es para la capa de presentación.

Es así? Solamente se diferencian en ese punto o hay más connotaciones?

Answer (score 4):

En principio así es :

- @Component: Es el estereotipo general y permite anotar un bean para que Spring lo considere uno de sus objetos.
- @Repository: Es el estereotipo que se encarga de dar de alta un bean para que implemente el patrón repositorio que es el encargado de almacenar datos en una base de datos o repositorio de información que se necesite. Al marcar el bean con esta anotación Spring aporta servicios transversales como conversión de tipos de excepciones.
- @Service : Este estereotipo se encarga de gestionar las operaciones de negocio más importantes a nivel de la aplicación y aglutina llamadas a varios repositorios de forma simultánea. Su tarea fundamental es la de agregador.
- @Controller : El último de los estereotipos que es el que realiza las tareas de controlador y gestión de la comunicación entre el usuario y el aplicativo. Para ello se apoya habitualmente en algún motor de plantillas o librería de etiquetas que facilitan la creación de páginas.

Pero podemos observar que como cada una tiene un contexto para su implementación pueden existir casos en los cuales se comporten de manera diferente a la esperada, ya sea por el ciclo de vida del bean o por que tienen una funcionalidad extra.

> @Service vs. @Repository vs. @Component
>   Nótese que en la versión actual de Spring la anotación @Service no tiene una semántica definida distinta a la de @Component. Es decir, simplemente le ayuda al que lee el código a saber que el bean pertenece a la capa de negocio y por lo demás es indiferente usar una u otra. La anotación @Repository sí tiene efecto sobre la transaccionalidad automática, como veremos en la siguiente sesión. No obstante, el equipo de desarrollo de Spring se reserva la posibilidad de añadir semántica a estas anotaciones en futuras versiones del framework.

**Usar las anotaciones con cuidado.**

Fuentes:

- http://www.arquitecturajava.com/spring-stereotypes/
- http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/publico/spring-2012-13/sesion01-apuntes.html

Answer (score 0):

Los conceptos de @Component, @Repository, @Service y @Controller:

@Component es un estereotipo genérico para los componentes manejados por Spring, @Repository, @Service, y @Controller son especializaciones de @Component para usos más específicos:

- @Repository para persistencia
- @Service para servicios y transacciones
- @Controller para controladores MVC

¿Por qué usar @Repository, @Service, @Controller por sobre @Component? Podemos anotar nuestras clases de componentes con @Component, pero en lugar de eso sí utilizamos alguna de las alternativa anteriores en donde le corresponda, nuestras clases se adaptan más y mejor en cada caso particular. Por ejemplo en cómo son procesadas y en cómo se relacionan con aspectos específicos de spring.

Comment: Respuesta reportada como copia de : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66548/como-crear-repository-en-spring/174653#174653 Revisar [answer].

Comment: No entiendo porque la reportas como copia de mi misma respuesta en otra pregunta. Es algo que aprendí en un curso y creo que les vale a las 2 preguntas. Porque las das como copia?.

Comment: La reporto el sistema, y no responde en realidad a la pregunta, te sugiero revises [answer].

Comment: Vale, no sé porqué tenía la respuesta duplicada, fue un error mio, existe alguna manera de recuperar los 25 puntos que perdí por el error de ctrl+v ????

Comment: A que te refieres, es una respuesta que realizaste? @UHDate

Answer (score 0):

Estás en lo cierto.

Como bien dice la [documentación de Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations), **@Component** es el estereotipo principal e indica que una clase con esta anotación es un component o Bean de Spring.

**@Repository**, **@Service** y **@Controller** son especificaciones de la anotación **@Component** para casos concretos, por ejemplo, para la persistencia de datos, servicios o para la capa de presentación respectivamente.

De todas maneras no sólo se diferencian en este punto, las clases anotadas con **@Service**, **@Repository** o **@Controller** tendran otros beneficios que no obtendrías con la anotación **@Component** ya que algunos de los Spring modules procesan de manera distinta estas anotaciones.

Por ejemplo, *Spring Data JPA* procesará **@Repository** e intentará remplazar con implementaciones de todas las interfaces marcadas con esta anotación. Otro ejemplo, *Spring Web MVC* procesará **@Controller**, y usará las clases marcadas con dicha anotación en los mapeos de las URL.