# para que sirven las anotaciones de estereotipos en spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Revisando un poco sobre los conceptos de spring-boot, vi que existe

```
 @Component
```

el cual se divide en 3

```
@Controller
@Service
@Repository
```

leendo un poco, cada uno tiene un fin, llegue a la conclusion que

```
@Controller -->sirve para las presentaciones
@Service    -->sirve para los servicios
@Repository -->sirve para las persistencias
```

no tengo muy en claro sobre las presentaciones, que es una presentacion? un controller no es el que se encarga de enlazar la vista con la logica del negocio?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Anotaciones de componentes Spring](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35508/anotaciones-de-componentes-spring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola buen dìa  te comento un poco sobre  **stereotypes** de Spring :

¿Cuales son los Spring Stereotypes? . Spring define un conjunto de anotaciones core que categorizan cada uno de los componentes asociandoles una responsabilidad concreta.

Si lo vemos a  manera de diagrama tenemos en el nivel superior :

```
                 **@Component**



**@Repository**    **@Controller**    **@Service**
```

**@Component**: Es el estereotipo general y permite anotar un bean para que Spring lo considere uno de sus objetos.

**@Repository**: Es el estereotipo que se encarga de dar de alta un bean para que implemente el patrón repositorio que es el encargado de almacenar datos en una base de datos o repositorio de información que se necesite. Al marcar el bean con esta anotación Spring aporta servicios transversales como conversión de tipos de excepciones.

```
**@Repository** ----------------> BD
```

**@Service** : Este estereotipo se encarga de gestionar las operaciones de negocio más importantes a nivel de la aplicación y aglutina llamadas a varios repositorios de forma simultánea. Su tarea fundamental es la de agregador.

```
                   |----@Repository
                   |----@Repository
@Service  ---------|----@Repository
                   |----@Repository
                   |----@Repository
```

**@Controller** : El último de los estereotipos que es el que realiza las tareas de controlador y gestión de la comunicación entre el usuario y el aplicativo. Para ello se apoya habitualmente en algún motor de plantillas o librería de etiquetas que facilitan la creación de páginas.

```
@Controller  ------------>   @Service --------------> @Repository
    |                                       |
    |                                       |--------> @Repository
    |                                       |
    |                                       |--------> @Repository
    |                                       |   
   VIEW                                     |--------> @Repository
```

Agrego ejemplo:

```
@Repository
public class CircleDaoImpl implements CircleDao
{
    private Point center;
    ----
}

@Service
public class CircleServiceImpl implements CircleService
{
    private Point center;
    ----
}

@Controller
public class CircleController
{
    private Point center;
    ----
}
```

Comment: @x-rw `@RestController` extiende de `@Controller` y le agrega soporte para que las peticiones de la clase atienda los request con los elementos básicos de servicios REST p.e. aceptar el body como JSON o XML, las respuestas de los métodos se convierten a JSON o XML, entre otras cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Estas anotaciones están basadas en el patrón [MVC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador). A saber:

Las clases decoradas con la anotación `@Controller` sirven como la C de MVC. Cabe resaltar que el verdadero controlador en Spring MVC es la clase `DispatchServlet` que usará las clases `@Controller` específicas para atender las peticiones en base al mapeo de las URLs declaradas.

Las clases decoradas con la anotación `@Service` deberían servir para tu capa de servicio o lógica de negocio. **Aquí es donde colocas la lógica de negocio de tu aplicación, reglas de negocio, entre otros**.

Las clases decoradas con la anotación `@Repository` deberían servir para la capa de acceso a datos. Aquí deberías colocar la lógica de CRUD: inserción, actualización (update), eliminación (física y/o lógica), consultas (select).

Las clases `@Service`, `@Repository` y tus clases de entidad serán la M de MVC. Tus archivos JSP y otras tecnologías de vista (JSTL, mustache, etc) conforman la V de MVC.

Las clases `@Controller` solo deberían tener acceso a las clases `@Service` mediante interfaces. De manera similar, las clases `@Service` solo deberían tener acceso a otras clases `@Service` y a un conjunto específico de clases `@Repository` mediante interfaces.

Ejemplo:

```
//Entidades
public class Recibo {
    private List<DetalleRecibo>
}
public class Producto { }
public class DetalleRecibo {
    Producto producto;
}

//DAOs, Repositorios, etc
public interface ReciboDao {
    void guardar(Recibo recibo);
}
//nota: estas anotaciones van a nivel de clase, NO a nivel de interfaz
@Repository
public class ReciboDaoImpl implements ReciboDao {
    //implementa los métodos
    //puede mandarlo a archivo, usar JDBC u otro framework
    //como Hibernate, JPA, MyBatis, jOOQ
    //o usar un repositorio de datos externo como servicios REST
}

public interface ProductoDao {
    Producto obtener(int id);
    void actualizar(Producto producto);
}
@Repository
public class ProductoDaoImpl implements ProductoDao {
    //implementación...
}

//Service
public interface ProductoService {
    Producto obtener(int id);
    void actualizarStock(Producto productoConStockActualizado);
}
@Service
public class ProductoServiceImpl implements ProductoService {
    //se le asocia al ProductoDao (interfaz)
    //ojo que debería acceder de manera vertical/jerárquica
    //al dao asociado a la entidad Producto
    @Autowired
    private ProductoDao productoDao;

    @Override
    public Producto obtener(int id) {
        return productoDao.obtener(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void actualizarStock(Producto productoConStockActualizado) {
        //ejemplo minimalista y básico
        //la implementación de un caso de uso como el de aquí debería
        //considerar más elementos
        Producto actual = obtener(productoConStockActualizado.getId());
        if (actual.getStock() - productoConStockActualizado.getStock() < 0)
            throw new MiExcepcion("Producto no puede tener stock negativo");
        productoDao.actualizar(productoConStockActualizado);
    }
}

public interface ReciboService {
    Recibo generaRecibo(List<DetalleRecibo> listaDetalleRecibo);
    void guardar(Recibo recibo);
}
@Service
public class ReciboServiceImpl {
    //se le asocia a ReciboDao, similar a la relación
    //entre ProductoService y ProductoDao
    @Autowired
    private ReciboDao reciboDao;
    //Nota: si ReciboServiceImpl quiere consultar u operar
    //con la información de la entidad Producto
    //en lugar de asociarse a ProductoDao se asociará
    //a ProductoService puesto que su implementación posee
    //reglas de negocio a usar en la aplicación
    @Autowired
    private ProductoService productoService;

    @Override
    public Recibo generaRecibo(List<DetalleRecibo> listaDetalleRecibo) {
        //usar la información de detalle del recibo
        //para armar y generar un recibo
        //ejemplo
        for (DetalleRecibo detalle : listaDetalleRecibo) {
            Producto producto = detalle.getProducto();
            productoService.actualizarStock(producto);
        }
        //más procesamiento...
        //se retorna el recibo generado
    }

    @Override
    public void guardar(Recibo recibo) {
        reciboDao.guardar(recibo);
    }
}

@Controller
public class VentaController {
    @Autowired
    private ReciboService reciboService;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public void guardaRecibo() {
        //procesa la información recibida
        //genera el recibo, lo guarda, etc...
    }
}
```

---

Adaptado de [mi respuesta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355411/1065197).

Comment: Claro que sí. Cuando ejecutas spring boot y tienes el log por lo menos en nivel info (o debug o trace) podrás encontrar una traza (log) con este mensaje: "Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]". Considera que el `DispatchServlet` es el corazón de Spring MVC. Si no lo carga, simplemente Spring MVC no funciona.

Comment: Si lo puedes hacer en Spring, de hecho lo puedes hacer en Spring Boot. ¿Qué es lo que necesitas hacer exactamente?

Comment: Quien crea los beans y demás es el contexto de spring, conocido como `ApplicationContext` (algunas implementaciones: `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, etc). La clase `DispatchServlet` hace uso del `ApplicationContext` para obtener los beans y demás componentes que usará para derivar la atención de las peticiones (requests) y conversión de información p.e. convertir un objeto a formato JSON y generar la respuesta del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Por medio del controlador tu enlazas la vista a una ruta, accediendo por medio de los métodos, `get`, `post`, `put`, `patch`, `delete`, etc, entonces con `@Controler` tratas de decirle a Spring que ese es un controlador y con `@RequestMapping` lo mapeas, también esta `@RestController` que con ese lo que haces es para servicios restful es decir que en vez de lanzar tus vistas en html lanzas tus datos en JSON