# Como crear @repository en spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

por que cuando se crea un repository

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {
```

que significa `<Book,Long>`, para que sirve o que?

Comment: Falta incluir los buscado/investigado sobre lo que se pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Book es la entidad que representa la tabla de tu base de datos.

Ejemplo:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="name_table")
public class NameTableEntity {
//fields
}
```

Cabe anotar que el Repository lo puedes crear por anotación, para evitar la configuración por XML:

```
@Repository 
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {
//methods
}
```

Comment: y que clase de metodos existiria? revise algunos codigos que no hay nada de metodos en los repositorios

Comment: Cuando heredas de la clase JpaRepository tienes acceso a metodos por defecto sobre la entidad, talvez esto te sirva: (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html), por ejemplo este es un metodo basico para obtener de la BD un registro por ID: `findOne(ID id)`

Answer (score 0):

El repositorio es una interface y extiende de la interface JpaRepository que contiene genéricos , El primero es la clase de la entidad y el segundo es la clase del identificador(Id)

Ejemplo 1:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="name_table")
public class NameTableEntity {
    @Id
    long id;
}
```

El repositorio seria:

```
@Repository 
public interface NameTableRepository extends JpaRepository<NameTableEntity,Long> {
//methods
}
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="name_table")
public class NameTableEntity {
    @Id
    String id;
}
```

El repositorio seria:

```
@Repository 
public interface NameTableRepository extends JpaRepository<NameTableEntity,String> {
//methods
}
```

Para que sirven?, bueno la interfaz JpaRepository contiene métodos definidos para guardar, buscar y borrar, algunos por ejemplo:

```
List<T> findAll();
<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
<S extends T> S findOne(Example<S> example);
```

ejemplo 1:

```
List<NameTableEntity> findAll();
NameTableEntity save(NameTableEntity nameTableEntity);
NameTableEntity findOne(Long id);
```

ejemplo 2:

```
List<NameTableEntity> findAll();
NameTableEntity save(NameTableEntity nameTableEntity);
NameTableEntity findOne(String id);
```

Answer (score 0):

JpaRepository al final extiende de CrudRepository, pero a un nivel mas bajo, el cual te va a facilitar casi todo el trabajo con las funciones JPA ya que los métodos find, save, delete, update, findbyid etc están implementados de manera transparente para tí.

Es por ello que tienes que definir `JpaRepository<Book,Long>` donde long es el tipo de dato de la clave primaria de la entidad y Book es la propia entidad en sí que se utilizará para autogenerar las funciones que te he comentado antes.
Un saludo.

Comment: Respuesta reportada como copia de : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35508/anotaciones-de-componentes-spring/174656#174656 Revisar [answer].

Comment: La respuesta la  reporto el sistema, y no responde en realidad a la pregunta, te sugiero revises [answer].